# Diferentes formas de fazer uma query que realiza uma junção SQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query, join

Eu aprendi a fazer consultas SQL com junções da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT u.NOME, e.RUA 
FROM usuarios u, endereco e 
WHERE e.ID_USUARIO = u.ID 
ORDER BY u.NOME
```

Como é possível perceber, a query busca o nome dos usuários e a rua do seu endereço (utilizando apelidos para simplificar os nomes das tabelas). Sobre a forma como esta query foi estruturada, as dúvidas são as seguintes:

- Isso é uma forma simplificada de fazer junções por não utilizar explicitamente JOIN, LEFT ON e instruções do tipo?
- Como ficaria a mesma query utilizando as instruções para junção explicitamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Isso é uma forma simplificada de fazer junções por não utilizar explicitamente JOIN, LEFT ON e instruções do tipo?

Não diria uma forma "simplificada", diria uma forma "alternativa" para fazer INNER join, pois fazer left / right / full outer seria mais trabalhosa.

Eu particularmente prefiro fazer o `join` utilizando a palavra-chave, pois separa as condições de join das condições da query. 
Basicamente: deixa o `join` fazer o trabalho de `join` e deixa o "`where`" fazer trabalho de "`where`"

> Como ficaria a mesma query utilizando as instruções para junção explicitamente?

```
SELECT u.NOME, e.RUA
FROM usuarios u
INNER JOIN endereco e ON e.ID_USUARIO = u.ID
ORDER BY u.NOME
```